# Snapping to grid

Tags: gui-design, grid, mouse

What is a good threshold for a UI which allows users to place objects, snapping them to a grid? 25% of the grid size? Less or more? Should the user be able to change this?

Comment: I believe it depends on the grid size and object size. I think you should test it against your users. I don't think you should let users change it, but sometimes it could be useful to switch it off (temporary or until it will be switched on again).

Comment: you temporarily disable it by holding Ctrl (Windows) while dragging, god I hate graphics editors that doesn't provide this...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 100% with @AndroidHustle on this one.  Photoshop is probably the most prolific example using it today; it also happens to be a feature I love dearly.  A good snap threshold for me is around 10-15% of the grid size, any larger and it just becomes too much of a pain.  Also, be sure to implement arrow-key movement as well (I use those all the time).